# Assigning values to letters and summing a sequence (not based on alphabetic order)

Tags: python

In Python, I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a value to a letter in a sequence and then ask for the sum of that sequence. So far, I have seen this only based on alphabetical order. What I have is a list of sequences:

For example: `ACEPAAG` (with one sequence per row) and would like to assign values to the letters: `A = 100`, `P = 150` etc. and then sum that sequence.

So far I have come across enumerate:

```
import string
d = {c: i for i,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 150)}
d 
word = "AGP"
score = sum(d[c] for c in word)
score
```

I understand this just adds 150 to and alphabetical list, is there a way of altering this so that I can choose what value goes with which letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map two lists into a dictionary like:

```
l = map(chr, range(65, 91))

print l
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

n = range(0, 27)

print n
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]

d = dict(zip(l,n))

print d
{'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 4, 'D': 3, 'G': 6, 'F': 5, 'I': 8, 'H': 7, 'K': 10, 'J': 9, 'M': 12, 'L': 11, 'O': 14, 'N': 13, 'Q': 16, 'P': 15, 'S': 18, 'R': 17, 'U': 20, 'T': 19, 'W': 22, 'V': 21, 'Y': 24, 'X': 23, 'Z': 25}
```

So, you can join a list with the numbers that you need.

```
score = sum(d[c] for c in word)
print score
21
```

Comment: Thank you Andre, this worked really well, the only problem I have now is fitting this into a loop so I can do this row by row. I have set up the two maps and then tried:::    with open('*.txt', 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
       if 'str' in line:
          break
          for line in f:
              score = sum(d[c] for c in line)
              print score
but this doesn't seem to work, could you comment as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Vron Sure, I don't understand very well, but I will try comment! If you have do set row by row. You can create a file *.txt containing each line 27 numbers separated by commas. After that, make a loop reading a file like that:
`try:
    f = open("c:\\temp\\listval.txt", "r")
    try:
        lines = f.readlines()
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass    
l = map(chr, range(65, 91))
num_list = []
for i in lines:
    num_list.append(i.strip().split(','))   
for num_line in num_list:  
 d = dict(zip(l,num_line))
 word = "AGP"
 score = sum(int(d[c]) for c in word)
 print score`

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is creating a list v with all the values, where the value at index 0 is for A, the value at index 25 is for Z, etc.

Then instead of using 'i' as you use it, use it as the index of v:

```
a = {c: v[i] for i,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}
```

This way you can choose what value you would like every letter to be.

Remember that for this to work, there must be at least 26 elements in v, otherwise you will get an index out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a value to a letter in a sequence and then ask for the sum of that sequence.

I don't know what you're doing in your OP so I'm just going to answer based off what I think you're doing. You're trying to sum up the ASCII values of a sequence of letters, right?

```
sequence_of_letters = "A sequence of letters and characters is better known as a string!"

print sum([ord(x) for x in sequence_of_letters]) # ord gives you the ASCII value
>>>6049
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not quite, I wanted to assign by own values to the letters as well, but the others have chipped in, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About your comment in my answer:

File with lines like that:

```
156, 731, 942, 15, 514, 48, 95, 607, 282, 30, 733, 444, 135, 367, 236, 404, 799, 276, 854, 937, 469, 450, 999, 327, 970, 716, 96    
621, 536, 358, 502, 745, 583, 899, 653, 496, 311, 451, 951, 819, 658, 77, 44, 593, 523, 754, 326, 647, 232, 916, 806, 289, 529, 918
```

*And code like that:*

```
try:
    f = open("c:\\temp\\listvalues.txt", "r")
    try:
        lines = f.readlines()
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass    

l = map(chr, range(65, 91))

num_list = []
for i in lines:
    num_list.append(i.strip().split(','))   

for num_line in num_list:  
    d = dict(zip(l,num_line))
    word = "AGP"
    score = sum(int(d[c]) for c in word)
    print score
```